# SYS(3050) is throwing Function argument value,type or count is invalid error

Tags: function, memory-management, shared-memory, foxpro

Earlier i had an issue of not enough memory for file mapping.

Then as advised by few experts I used following code in my main program and that solves the issue and worked fine.

SYS(3050,1,MIN(536870912,VAL(SYS(3050,1,0))))
SYS(3050,2,MIN(536870912,VAL(SYS(3050,1,0))))

But recently one of client's machine is upgraded to Windows 7 64 bit from XP 32 bit. After that when the system is starting 
it is throwing an error of Function argument value, type or count is invalid at SYS(3050) line.

If I omit  this and continues then not enough memory for file mapping is occurs.

Can anybody advise what i should do to overcome this issue? Is it because of 64 bit OS of Windows 7 (because other two machines with Windows 7 and 32 bit are working properly)

Comment: I would say something else is the problem - I have never needed to adjust that setting in 20+ years and to answer the other question we have thousands of customers on 64-bit Windows. What was it that caused you to go down the sys(3050) route in the first place?

Comment: Hi Alan, It said that VFP 7 is unable to allocate the memory when RAM is more than 2GB, there for it is requested to set the minimum and maximum memory needed for VFP. Then I placed that SYS(3050) in my main which then solve the issue

Comment: My only suggestion really is use VFP9 SP2.

Answer (score 0):

As Alan B said, the problems with 'not enough memory for file mapping' tend to go away when switching to VFP9 SP2 (it's the one fly in the ointment when using VFP8 SP1 which is otherwise the most solid of the lot).

If switching to VFP9 is not an option then I would suggest factoring out the nested `SYS(3050,1,0)` calls and sanitising the result before feeding it into `VAL()`. At the very least it would pinpoint more accurately the place where the problem occurs, to guide further investigation with the aid of a debugger or a tool like IDA.

The original code already caps the parameter at 536870912, which is well below the threshold of 2^31 at which SYS(3050) throws a range error. However, the parameter must be strictly positive, which requires adding a `MAX()` term:

```
local nLimit
nLimit = max(1, min(536870912, val(sys(3050, 1))))
sys(3050, 1, m.nLimit)
sys(3050, 2, m.nLimit)
```

Background: calling the function with a limit parameter of 0 is the same as calling it without a limit (i.e. it **gets** the limit instead of **setting** it). Calling the function with a negative parameter causes it to blow with a range error.